# How to serve SPA on root using Azure AD's AuthorizeforScopes in a BFF

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I am pulling my hair out on this issue and I wonder if anyone here could help me out. If not, does anyone know who can?

My situation is that I have a BFF (Backend-for-frontend) that serves my Angular SPA. I use Azure AD Auth.
I use .NET Core 5 and the up to date Azure AD nuget libs

The BFF is useful because it prevents my Auth tokens from being saved in the browser; the BFF saves it in a http-only secure cookie so the SPA has no knowledge of the user; it has to ask the API about the user.
The BFF also ensures that you can only access the SPA if you are logged in
The BFF also reverse proxies calls to `/api` to the actual API; which is hosted inside our k8s cluster so you can't reach it from the internet

The diagram basically looks like this. See image.

[image: Setup diagram]

My problem is that I need to use `AuthorizeForScopes` for Azure AD Auth but this requires stupid workarounds. As far as I can find online I must put this on a Controller/Action like so:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "Scopes")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return PhysicalFile($"{_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath}/ClientApp/dist/index.html", "text/html");
}
```

This means that if you go to `/`, you will hit this endpoint and get served the `index.html`. This isn't a super neat setup because I would rather just let the `UseSpa()` in `Startup.cs` handle this. But I believe this is necessary because I can't just use `AuthorizeForScopes` in my middleware.

Another problem is that this doesn't work during development because there the `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer()` in `Startup.cs` handles all this. If you run this during development you get an error cuz it can't find the index.html

The current solution I have on prod is that the code I posted above instead redirects to `/home` which the SPA handles, so that way if you go to `/` you get redirected to `/home` and the BFF pipeline then redirects you to the SPA and boom, it all works. But this means I can't run my SPA on `/`

I currently have the following `Startup.cs` setup for my pipeline. I removed unnecessary code.

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/errorstatus/{0}");

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Proxy calls to the API through the BFF so the API can only be reached from within the cluster. This is more secure
app.Map("/api", true, config => RunApiProxy(/* Stuff here */));

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
});

if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // During development we serve files from the dev-server, not from the location of the spa static files
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}

// Redirect the user to authenticate if the user isnt at this moment
// All static frontend related files are served using the UseSpaStaticFiles middleware
// What's left is the index.html
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.OpenIdConnect);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});

if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Forward devserver socket calls during development
    app.MapWhen(p => p.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/sockjs-node"), config =>
    {
        config.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
        });
    });
}

// Serve the angular app
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
    }
});
```

**How do I implement `AuthorizeForScopes` without that Action method posted above so I can serve my SPA on `/` only if the user is `[Authorized]` and `[AuthorizeForScopes]`?**

Answer (score 1):

> How do I implement AuthorizeForScopes without that Action method posted above so I can serve my SPA on / only if the user is [Authorized] and [AuthorizeForScopes]

There are two ways of doing this in the `startup.cs` > `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method.

Option 1:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
{
    o.Filters.Add(new RequiredScopeAttribute(new[] { "access_as_user" }));
});
```

This will automatically add the Scope attribute to all controllers, but this will not work if you have endpoints with `[AllowAnonymous]`.

To get around this the other way is to add your own authorization policy in the same `ConfigureServices` method for scope:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
var authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme })
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireAssertion(ctx =>
        {
            // Attempt with Scp claim
            Claim scopeClaim = ctx.User.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.Scp);

            // Fallback to Scope claim name
            if (scopeClaim == null)
            {
                scopeClaim = ctx.User.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.Scope);
            }
            return scopeClaim != null && scopeClaim.Value.Split(' ').Intersect(new[] { "access_as_user" }).Any();
        })
        .Build();
    o.DefaultPolicy = authPolicy;
});
```

The second option sets this auth policy as default for all routes via `o.DefaultPolcy = authPolcy` but unlike the first option this can be overridden by using `[AllowAnonymous]` on your method/controller.

You can also use `o.AddPolicy("authMeUpScotty", authPolicy)` instead of `o.DefaultPolicy` and use `[Authorize(Policy = "authMeUpScotty")]` if it was only for particular endpoints.

Hope this helps!